# iLO3: Multiple SSH commands

Tags: linux, shell

is there a way to run multiple commands in HPs integrated Lights-Out 3 system via SSH? I can login to iLO and run a command line by line, but I need to create a small shell-script, to connect to iLO and to run some commands one by one.

This is the line I use, to get information about the iLO-version:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i dsa_key administrator@<iLO-IP> "version"
```

Now, how can I do something like this?

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i dsa_key administrator@<iLO-IP> "version" "show /map1 license" "start /system1"
```

This doesn't work, because iLO thinks it's all one command. But I need something to login into iLO, run these commands and then exit from iLO. It takes too much time to run them one after the other because every login into iLO-SSH takes ~5-6 seconds (5 commands = 5*5 seconds...).

I've also tried to seperate the commands directly in iLO after manual login but there is no way to use multiple commands in one line. Seems like one command is finished by pressing return.

iLO-SSH Version is: SM-CLP Version 1.0

The following solutions did NOT work:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i dsa_key administrator@<iLO-IP> "version; show /map1 license; start /system1"
/usr/bin/ssh -i dsa_key administrator@<iLO-IP> "version && show /map1 license && start /system1"
```

Comment: Already tried the seperation via semicolon. This "version;show /map1 license;start /system1" results in: error_tag=COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED

Comment: I'm using HP ProLiant DL120 G7 with iLO3 advanced

Answer (score 3):

This Python module is for HP iLO Management. check it out

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-hpilo/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your commands in a file (named `theFile` in this example):

```
version
show /map1 license
start /system1
```

Then:

```
ssh -i dsa_key administrator@iLO-IP < theFile
```

Semicolons and such won't work because you're using the iLO shell on the other side, not a normal *nix shell.  So above I redirect the file, with newlines intact, as if you were typing all that into the session by hand.  I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work :( I don't get anything back from iLO. When I use the "< file" at the end, nothing really happens. I can only stop the command by pressing CTRL+C. Checked the "file" several times but it's exactly one command per line as you said.

Comment: Interesting.  Would you entertain writing a script in say Python to do this?  You could then use an ssh library, rather than just the program, to get the exact behavior you want (send one command, get its output, then send another...all without logging in twice).

Comment: Hm, I think that's the only solution for this "problem". I was hoping that there would be an easier way to do this just via shell-script, then I only had to modify my current script etc. But I think I have to use python for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to treat iLO like it's a normal shell, but its really HP's dopy interface.

That being said, the easiest way is to put all the commands in a file and then pipe it to ssh (sending all of the newline characters):

```
echo -e "version\nshow /map1 license\nstart /system1" | /usr/bin/ssh -i dsa_key administrator@<iLO-IP>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. Same problem like the other solution with sending the file to the system. No output, nothing happens, can only cancel via CTRL+C. (waited several minutes)

Comment: Yeah this is equivalent to my first solution (which for some strange reason doesn't work).

Comment: @user313133 so it looks like HP has some sample scripts on the iLO CD, and the corresponding webpage is: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=US&swItem=MTX-a17bde2a8b0643c3b54a8d41f2&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=1146658

Comment: There are only XML and perl scripts in this file. No shell-scripts for direct SSH access (command line).

Comment: @user313133 the perl script does the ssh part of it.

Comment: Okay, I think using perl + xml scripts is the best solution and faster than SSHing to the server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's a messy workaround, but would you might fancy using [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)? Your script in `expect` would look something like that:

```
# Make an ssh connection
spawn ssh -i dsa_key administrator@<iLO-IP>
# Wait for command prompt to appear
expect "$"
# Send your first command
send "version\r"
# Wait for command prompt to appear
expect "$"
# Send your second command
send "show /map1 license\r"
# Etc...
```

On the bright side, it's guaranteed to work. On the darker side, it's a pretty clumsy workaround, very prone to breaking if something goes not the way it should (for example, command prompt character would appear in `version` output, or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same case and wish to avoid to run a lot of `plink` commands. So I've seen you can add a file with the `-m` option but apparently it executes just one command at time :-(

```
plink -ssh Administrator@AddressIP -pw password -m test.txt
```

What's the purpose of the file ? Is there a special format for this file ?

My current text file looks like below:

```
set /map1/oemhp_dircfg1 oemhp_usercntxt1=CN=TEST
set /map1/oemhp_dircfg1 oemhp_usercntxt2=CN=TEST2
...
```

Is there a solution to execute these two commands ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and ended up using the "RIBCL over HTTPS" interface to the iLO.  This has advantages in that it is much more responsive than logging in/out over ssh.

Using curl or another command-line HTTP client try:

```
USERNAME=<YOUR_ILO_USERNAME>
PASSWORD=<YOUR_ILO_PASSWORD>
ILO_URL=https://<YOUR_ILO_IP>/ribcl
curl -k -X POST -d "<RIBCL VERSION=\"2.0\">
  <LOGIN USER_LOGIN=\"${USERNAME}\" PASSWORD=\"${PASSWORD}\">
    <RIB_INFO MODE="READ">
      <GET_FW_VERSION/>
      <GET_ALL_LICENSES/>
    </RIB_INFO>
    <SERVER_INFO MODE=\"write\">
      <SET_HOST_POWER HOST_POWER=\"Yes\">
    </SERVER_INFO>
  </LOGIN>
</RIBCL>" ${ILO_URL}
```

The formatting isn't exactly the same, but if you have the ability to access the iLO via HTTPS instead of only ssh, this may give you some flexibility.

More details on the various RIBCL commands and options may be found at [HP iLO 3 Scripting Guide (PDF)](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02774508-7%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).